# Testing using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am working on AngularJs Web based applications. I am testing the application using Protractor. It is something new for me. Now I want to inspect the Login button and want to click on that. The source code for that is

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" press-enter="" ng-click="validate()" tabindex="4">Login</a>
```

How can I inspect this button so that it can click on Login button and move forward?

Comment: I don't see any source code there. And what are the steps you want to do/inspect? It's not clear.

Comment: You should put your code here. Then we are able to help you

Comment: I got the solution for that. Thanks a lot for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to locate this element. The most appropriate one, I think, would be the ["by link text"](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText) location technique:

```
element(by.linkText("Login")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose multiple ways to click on this login button such as $,tagName, linkText

Page Class:

```
this.login = element(by.tagName("a"));

 this.clkLogin = function () {
        return this.login.click();
      }
```

call the function in spec class:

```
loginpage.clkLogin();
```